# kotlin inner class cant access private method outside?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hi i am new to kotlin and trying to simply invoke a private function from inside a inner anonymous class.

Below is the call:

```
      object callback : Callback<ResponseBody> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, response: Response<ResponseBody>?) {

            Log.d("jjj", " response is " + response.toString())
            displaySuccess()

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, t: Throwable?) {
        }

    }



      private fun displaySuccess(){
        Toast.makeText(activity,"succesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    }
```

both these snippet of code resides on a Fragment class and displaySuccess cant be accessed inside onResponse?

Comment: Are you getting any error? I suppose it is possible to access private functions from anonymous class.

Comment: It says unresolved reference under displaySuccess() line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `object` you're creating a singleton, which doesn't know how to access the class outside. You should define it as a class and instantiate it.

Comment: O ok. But i need to create this object and pass it on as a parameter . its a interface that i need to pass onto another function. A callback in other words

Comment: Yes, but you should define it as `class MyCallback : Callback<ResponseBody>` and then create it as `MyCallback()` (notice no `new` keyword, replaces the reference to the `callback` object). This means you're creating an object for each invocation, instead of using a singleton.

Comment: In other words, what you are using is a singleton (see here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations or https://antonioleiva.com/objects-kotlin/) and what you need is either what I've described you or this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions which is equivalent to Java's anonymous classes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the object like this:

```
val callback = object: Callback<ResponseBody> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, response: Response<ResponseBody>?) {
        //implementation
    }
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, t: Throwable?) {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

The one you are using is [object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations). To create an object of anonymous class, you have to use [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) instead. Their syntax are slightly different.